# Trignometric System Pointwise Convergence in $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Fix a dimension $d$, let us consider the system $A=\{e^{i(t\cdot x)}\}$. Here $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ is a variable and the set ranges over every $t \in \mathbb{R}^d$. I want to show that for every $\phi \in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$ there exists a sequence of functions chosen in $\text{span}A$ that converges pointwise to $\phi$. Here $C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is the set of all smooth compactly supported complex functions on $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Here is my attempt: let $\phi \in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be given. Use $K$ to denote the support of $\phi$. My first idea would be to use the Stone-Weirstrass theorem. If we restrict the domain just to $K$, then everything works out nicely because $\text{span}A$ satisfies all hypothesis: it is closed under addition, multiplication, scalar multiplication, and complex conjugate; it also separates points and vanishes at no point so that in fact I can get uniform convergence. However, since the domain is in $\mathbb{R}^d$ we are in trouble as I cannot make sure the limit goes to zero off $K$.

Is there a way to make my attempt work? If not, can the result be proven using some other methods?

Comment: Maybe use the following version of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem on page 142 of Folland's analysis book:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AWmv.png

Comment: I don't see how this applies. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Ah I didn't see the $i$. Maybe use Fourier inversion and Riemann sums. Given $\phi \in C_c^{\infty}$, $\hat{\phi} \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\phi(x) = \int \hat{\phi}(\xi)e^{ix \cdot \xi}\,d\xi$. I'm thinking now about in what sense the Riemann sums converge.

Comment: You can use a sequence $K_n$ of compact sets containing the support of $\phi$ with $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} \mathring{K}_n=\mathbb R^d$ and apply Stone Weierstraß on each $K_n$ to find $f_n$ in the span of $A$ with $\sup\{|\phi(x)-f_n(x)|: x\in K_n\}<1/n$. This sequence $f_n$ converges locally uniformly (and, in particular, pointwise) on $\mathbb R^d$ to $\phi$.